# Why does my version of strcmp not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, strcmp

I have a my own version of strcmp that looks like this

```
int strcmp(char str1[], char str2[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((str1[i] == str2[i]) && (str1[i] != '\0'))
    {
        i++;
    }

    if (str1[i] > str2[i])
        return 1;

    if (str1[i] < str2[i])
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

And my test case is

```
char a[20];
char b[20];
b[0] = 'f';
a[0] = 'f';


cout << strcmp(b, a) << endl;
```

However, I get the output of 1, meaning they are not equal to each other. If I swap a and b's position in the function call I get -1. I am not sure why I am unable to get the 0 return in my comparison when my char's are both 'f'. I feel like this is so basic and I don't know why my comparison is off

```
str1[i] > str2[i]
```

Comment: What do you think is in the indices 1 through 19?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've left your arrays uninitialized and only changed the first elements of each. This means that instead of comparing the strings "f" and "f" against one another, you're comparing two blocks of 20 bytes each against one another, except that each of the blocks starts with an "f". (Actually, since those arrays aren't null-terminated, you're comparing two random regions of memory together!)

Try changing your test cases so that you use `strcpy` to initialize the arrays. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Wow, I see exactly what the problem is there. I assumed that declaring a char would fill all unused spaces with null terminators at first.

Comment: @user3328187 You can initialize a `char` array to have nothing but null terminators in it by writing `char arr[size] = {0};`, in case that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your test case is broken, you are missing the NUL terminator, so you are comparing two strings that start with an `f` and go on with whatever garbage is on the stack.

You can fix it by explicitly adding the terminator, like:

```
a[1]=b[1]=0;
```

or initializing them directly with the relevant string literal:

```
char a[20]="f";
char b[20]="f";
```

or by using an strcpy, or comparing directly two string literals

```
strcmp("f", "f")
```

(once you added `const` to your parameters).